# JdbcMessageHandler batch update - not to cancel everything on one error

Tags: jdbc, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

lets say the `payload()` is ArrayList with n items, one of the items has a pk duplicate value (that already exists in table and causes duplicate violation).

When this happens , none of other valid items inserted to database.
Is it possible that the  batch  operation will insert valid (and will push to errorChannel only problematic items)?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=..)
public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler = new JdbcMessageHandler(dataSource, "INSERT INTO...");
    jdbcMessageHandler.setPreparedStatementSetter((ps, message) ->...

  return...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with such an assumption you just violate a purpose of batch insert: all or nothing.

You may  consider to `split` that list upfront and add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` into that `JdbcMessageHandler` to handle individual errors.

See more info about advising request handlers in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

Comment: suspected that this is how it is with batch. thanks